# What does "sizing" mean in this example?

Tags: meaning

What does "sizing" mean in the following quote from http://www.wikihow.com/Press-a-Shirt:

> Lightly spray the hanging shirt with sizing or spray starch (optional)
>   then remove the shirt from hanger.

My understanding is that in "spray the hanging shirt with sizing", "sizing" seems to be some fluid that will be sprayed on the hanging shirt. But as far as I know, "sizing" means  an action of changing the size of something.

Thanks!

Comment: -1 shows no research effort. Close General Reference.

Comment: @mata- OP is confused as to how *sizing* and *size* are related.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search provides the [following answer](http://www.americandrycleaner.com/node/742):

> Starch is vegetable-based (it’s formulated from wheat, corn or rice), while sizing is a resinous solution that can be either vegetable- or plastic-based.
>
> When starch is applied in place of sizing, the garment can become overly stiff, crease easily and wrinkle before and during wear. Because sizing adds body to fabric, it makes garments easier to finish, reduces wrinkling during wear, and keeps pleats and creases sharp.

Wikipedia also has a bit on [sizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizing#Textile_warp_sizing) and [desizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desizing) textiles (in manufacturing).

An [online video](http://www.ehow.com/video_4405084_starch-sizing_.html) also explains when to use sizing instead of starch.

As per the [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sizing#Noun):

> **sizing** (plural **sizings**) n. -
>
> 1. A gelatinous glue for glazing or sizing canvas, paper, plaster or wood; often made from animal skins.
> 2. paste

It is also referred to as [*size*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/size#Noun_2) and likely shares a similar etymology: "sise, syse (“regulation, control, limit”)". Like starch, it "controls" the stiffness of the cloth.

Comment: Thanks! Why is the liquid called sizing? I have tried, but I don't know how to answer you why.

Comment: @Tim The liquid is also referred to as *size*. The usual online sources didn't have a specific etymology but it would seem to be related to the origin of *size*:  "sise, syse (“regulation, control, limit”)". Like starch, it "controls" the stiffness of the cloth.

Answer (score 2):

**size** - *a semi-solid glutinous substance, prepared from materials similar to those which furnish glue, and used to mix with colours, to dress cloth or paper, and for various other purposes.*

(that's from OED, who say the origin is unclear).

*Size* can also be used as a verb with this sense (to apply, or treat with *size*). Sometimes the form *sizing* is used instead of *size* as a noun, but in my experience this isn't common, and I think it has a somewhat archaic tone.

Specifically in OP's context, the size/sizing is likely to be starch-based - its purpose being to stiffen the shirt-cloth to make it look smarter (not creased). Starch also thickens/stiffens more when heated (think of custard), so pressing with a hot iron will increase the effect, but isn't essential.

Comment: *Sizing* is more common in the US, or at least in the US military.

Comment: @Mark: I know it exists - Google Books claims 32 instances of ["spray sizing on"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22spray+sizing+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But ["spray **size** on"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22spray+size+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) has a claimed 92 instances, and that's the version I'm more familiar with. I suspect it would be just too difficult to find out whether there's a US/UK split here.